# Tensorflow federated can't be imported on google collabs notebook

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory, tf.keras, tensorflow-federated

I wrote following codes on a new google collabs notebook:

```
!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated-nightly

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_federated as tff
```

And I got these error messages while importing `tensorflow_federeated`:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/api/_v1/keras/experimental/__init__.py in <module>()
      8 from keras.feature_column.sequence_feature_column import SequenceFeatures
      9 from keras.layers.rnn.lstm_v1 import PeepholeLSTMCell
---> 10 from keras.optimizers.learning_rate_schedule import CosineDecay
     11 from keras.optimizers.learning_rate_schedule import CosineDecayRestarts
     12 from keras.premade_models.linear import LinearModel

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.optimizers.learning_rate_schedule'; 'keras.optimizers' is not a package
```

These errors seem to be spawning from the modules installed on the colabs itself, instead of my code.

Any idea on what can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Collab Defaults to 3.7 according to [a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72055790/3761924) But although the solution to upgrade to 3.9 did indeed upgrade to python 3.9, TFF still didn't work for me, even when I installed locally. So, find a different path.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue of "tff" not working in colab

Comment: Nope. Other libraries, like PySyft, that uses TFF doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I have been able to solve this issue and tried to give answer for that. You can also try that. I am pasting the link here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75439018/15249193
Might be it would be heplful for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all
it works fine in colab
!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated

!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-model-optimization

!pip install --quiet --upgrade nest-asyncio

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

%load_ext tensorboard

!pip install tensorflow
!pip install --quiet tensorflow-federated==0.20.0

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34445793)