# TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable when importing tensorflow_federated as tff

Tags: tensorflow, typeerror, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-federated

I'm working in colab notebook, and the importing of tff (import tensorflow_federated as tff) was working for months, but suddenly, now when I try to import tff as usual I faced this problem..

```
!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated
!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-model-optimization
!pip install --quiet --upgrade nest-asyncio

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_federated as tff
from tensorflow_model_optimization.python.core.internal import tensor_encoding as te

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-c8d605e9ca2e> in <module>()
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import tensorflow as tf
----> 4 import tensorflow_federated as tff
      5 
      6 from tensorflow_model_optimization.python.core.internal import tensor_encoding as te

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/common_libs/structure.py in <module>()
    263 
    264 def to_odict(struct: Struct,
--> 265              recursive: bool = False) -> collections.OrderedDict[str, Any]:
    266   """Returns `struct` as an `OrderedDict`, if possible.
    267 

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Even when I run it in the colab tutorial itself! in this link https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/docs/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification.ipynb I have the same issue!

Appreciate any idea or suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled the same with Google Colab since the default Google Colab is in Python 3.7. Here's what I did to make Google Colab upgrade to Python 3.9

```
!wget -O mini.sh https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x mini.sh
!bash ./mini.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!conda install -q -y jupyter
!conda install -q -y google-colab -c conda-forge
!python -m ipykernel install --name "py39" --user
```

Hope this helps you to move on as I did!

Answer (score 3):

The latest tensorflow_federated package need the Python version update to 3.9, hope this will help you.

Comment: when I upgrade it to 3.9, I got this error for pip Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip' ! can you give me the right way to upgrade python version with pip?

Comment: you can try to use ‘conda create -n new_env_name python=3.9’ to create a new conda environment and install tff package